# Replace values of one column based on other column conditions in shell

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a tab separated text file below. I want to match values in column 2 and replace the values in column 5. The condition is if there are X or Y in column 2, I want column 5 to have 1 just like in the result below.

```
1:935662:C:CA   1       0       935662  0
1:941119:A:G    2       0       941119  0
1:942934:G:C    3       0       942934  0
1:942951:C:T    X       0       942951  0
1:943937:C:T    X       0       943937  0
1:944858:A:G    Y       0       944858  0
1:945010:C:A    X       0       945010  0
1:946247:G:A    1       0       946247  0
```

result:

```
    1:935662:C:CA   1       0       935662  0
    1:941119:A:G    2       0       941119  0
    1:942934:G:C    3       0       942934  0
    1:942951:C:T    X       0       942951  1
    1:943937:C:T    X       0       943937  1
    1:944858:A:G    Y       0       944858  1
    1:945010:C:A    X       0       945010  1
    1:946247:G:A    1       0       946247  0
```

I tried `awk -F'\t' '{ $5 = ($2 == X  ? 1 : $2) } 1' OFS='\t' file.txt` but I am not sure how to match both X and Y in one step.

Comment: @mattb yes. I can do it one at a time, but not matching both X and Y at the same time. With something like `X|Y`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} $2=="X" || $2=="Y"{$5="1"}1' file
```

Output:

```
1:935662:C:CA   1       0       935662  0
1:941119:A:G    2       0       941119  0
1:942934:G:C    3       0       942934  0
1:942951:C:T    X       0       942951  1
1:943937:C:T    X       0       943937  1
1:944858:A:G    Y       0       944858  1
1:945010:C:A    X       0       945010  1
1:946247:G:A    1       0       946247  0
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want $5 to be zero (as opposed to remaining unchanged) if the condition is false:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {$5=($2 ~ /^[XY]$/)} 1' file
1:935662:C:CA   1       0       935662  0
1:941119:A:G    2       0       941119  0
1:942934:G:C    3       0       942934  0
1:942951:C:T    X       0       942951  1
1:943937:C:T    X       0       943937  1
1:944858:A:G    Y       0       944858  1
1:945010:C:A    X       0       945010  1
1:946247:G:A    1       0       946247  0
```